# How to get a nameserver IP from Linux CLI?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, networkmanager

When I connect to a wireless network from my laptop, Network Manager somehow requests a DNS nameserver IP from the router and writes it to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

How can I request a nameserver address from cli *without changing /etc/resolv.conf*, if I only know address of the gateway?

Comment: You don't even need to know the address of the gateway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Manager doesn't *somehow* requests the IP address of a name server from the router. When you connect to a network and request an IP address using DHCP — as opposed to statically configuring the IP address, default gateway, etc. yourself — the DHCP server *might* (but most likely will) give you the IP address of one or more DNS servers; which then can get saved into the file */etc/resolv.conf*.

> How can I request a name server address from CLI without changing */etc/resolv.conf*, if I only know address of the gateway?

You cannot. Why would you want to do that anyway?

You can always broadcast a DHCP query on the network and await a DHCP response which most likely will contain the IP address of the known DNS servers.

Comment: Yes, he can: `nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e wlan0`